# PHPUnit (4.7.7) tests work in cmd, but not in NetBeans (8.0.2)

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

First of all, what strange is that some tests in Netbeans are running, but just some that are in one level "deeper" don't work.

Structure:

```
Test
  ---Folder1
     ---Folder2
        ---Folder3
           ---Folder4
              ---Folder5
                 ---Folder6
                    ---testsThatWorkTest.php
                 ---Folder6-2
                    ---Folder7
                       ---testThatDontWorkTest.php
                    ---Folder7-2
                       ---testInHereWorkTest.php
  ---bootstrap.php
  ---phpunit.xml
```

Message I get in Netbeans in Output window:

```
PHPUnit 4.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:    No whitelist configured for code coverage
Time: 562 ms, Memory: 12.00Mb

No tests executed!

Generating code coverage report in PHP format ... done
```

Message I get in cmd:

```
PHPUnit 4.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:        No whitelist configured for code coverage
Time: 5.39 seconds, Memory: 20.75Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

Generating code coverage report in PHP format ... done
```

I will assume that all the settings are correct in netbeans (tools->options->php->phpunit and also in "Right-click" Properties->Testing) because of the working tests.

the phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit colors="true"
     bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="databaseTests">
        <directory>./Folder0/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="shopTests">
        <directory>./Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="testFolder7">
        <directory>./Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6-2/Folder7/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-php" target="./Logs/coverage.serialized"/>
    <log type="json" target="./Logs/logfile.json"/>
</logging>
<php>
    <includePath>.</includePath>
     ...........more vars const etc ....
</php>
</phpunit>
```

in bootstrap.php I have just some includes fore some other classes.

One of the not working Tests:

```
<?php

class testThatDontWorkTest extends Custom_Tests_DatabaseTestCase { 
//in this i just set getConnection()

public function getDataSet() {
    return $this->createXMLDataSet(TESTDIR . '/Database/XMLs/dbtests.xml');
}

public static function setUpBeforeClass() {
    init(); //some stuff in bootstrap
}

/**
 * Sets up the fixture, for example, opens a network connection.
 * This method is called before a test is executed.
 */
protected function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();
}

/**
 * Tears down the fixture, for example, closes a network connection.
 * This method is called after a test is executed.
 */
protected function tearDown() {
    parent::tearDown();
}

public function testaddError() {
    testThatDontWorkTest::addError();
    $queryTable = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable(
            'errors', 'SELECT * FROM errors'
    );
    $expectedTable = $this->createXmlDataSet(TESTDIR . '/Database
    /XMLs/expectedResult.xml')->getTable("errors");
    $this->assertTablesEqual($expectedTable, $queryTable);
}
}
```

I don't get why some test are working in Netbeans and others not.

**Edit1**: In Netbeans I just right-click on source -> Test or direct on test Right-click -> run.

And from cmd:

`php Lib/phpunit.phar --bootstrap bootstrap.php testThatDontWorkTest ./Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/Folder5/Folder6-2/Folder7/testThatDontWorkTest.php`

in the Test Folder

**Edit2**: also when I'm running the **shopTests** testsuit

```
phpunit --testsuite shopTests
```

only the tests in Folder6 and Folder7-2 are running, the tests in Folder7 not.

I also created a testsuite just for the Folder7

```
phpunit --testsuite testFolder7
```

and I get again:

```
PHPUnit 4.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:        No whitelist configured for code coverage

Time: 577 ms, Memory: 12.00Mb

No tests executed!

Generating code coverage report in PHP format ... done
```

**Edit3**: When I rename/refactor the folder Folder7->Folder8 works to run the tests. But when I re-generate the folders or files I get in the same problem. Any Idea what could be the problem?

Comment: in what way do you run your tests in netbeans and what command you use for cmd?

Comment: I edited my post. Just to be sure the Lib/phpunit.phar is the same as in Netbeans

Comment: does Netbeans output window logs a command he used to run your tests? something like you use to run tests in cmd

Comment: I have a Terminal, but that's not the idea. I want the test to work in Netbeans, because of the Test Results window, where I can see better which tests past which not.

Comment: i jsut suggest to figure out the command which Netbeans use to run your tests. probably it should be in the IDE's output(log) window. it may contain an answer

Comment: I think Netbeans runs this in CLI: *phpunit NetBeansSuite.php --run=<file-or-directory>*